# [助詞のような働きをする言葉 vs 助詞のような働きをする言葉の名詞につく形

Tags: meaning

I have 2 definitions as listed below:

1. [助詞のような働きをする言葉] + の + 名
   eg.
   a) 生命について本を書いた → 生命についての本
2. [助詞のような働きをする言葉の名詞につく形] + 名
   eg.
   a) そのバスは市の運営によって走っている → 市の運営によるバス
   b) A案に対して反対意見を言う → A案に対する反対意見

So My question is what is the difference between the 2 definitions, as from what I can see 1 means: a word that acts as a particle and 2 means a form attached to noun of words that acts as a particle.

So what I wanted to confirm is WHAT is the the NOUN of words that acts as a particle?
For example 2a would the noun be 市? and for 2b would it be A案?

If that's the case then what about 1a, isn't 生命 a noun also, so could it not fit into the definition of 2 also?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [this](https://www.kvbro.com/luyen-thi-jlpt/n3/ngu-phap-n3/bai-14a-%E6%96%87%E6%B3%95%E5%BD%A2%E5%BC%8F%E3%81%AE%E6%95%B4%E7%90%86%E3%80%80b-%E5%8A%A9%E8%A9%9E%E3%81%AE%E3%82%88%E3%81%86%E3%81%AA%E5%83%8D%E3%81%8D%E3%82%92%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E8%A8%80/) for example, 助詞のような働きをする言葉 refers to a group of phrases such as について, によって, に対して etc. Their 名詞につく形 should be those with the ending changed appropriately so that they connect to nouns (e.g. によって→による, に対して→に対する).

As for について, ついて does not conjugate, but ～についての can be considered 名詞につく形 of 助詞のような働きをする言葉 that ends in について, which makes the first rule unnecessary. Or both rules can be considered as the same rule depending on whether 助詞のような働きをする言葉's endings conjugate or not.

---

The rest of your questions should be resolved if you understand the above, but consider 生命について本を書いた. Here 生命について works like 助詞 on 本を書いた. When 生命について modifies 本, it becomes 生命について + の + 本. (As for the 2nd rule, NOUNs in the rules are バス and 反対意見.)